# How to implement a MIMO model with state space block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, state-space

I want to implement a state space model with 4 inputs and 4 outputs in Simulink. But the state space block has only one input and only one output. So what can I do here?

[image: Simulink State Space Block]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out just now. So all we have to use is a mux block for the input and demux block for outputs. 
[image]

Comment: Or even better: vectorise your inputs and outputs. Both blocks you have used for inputs & outputs support vectorised signals, so you only really need one block of each type. See for example [Determining the Output Dimensions of Source Blocks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/determining-output-signal-dimensions.html#bsud_ek-4) in the documentation.

Comment: @gustavoreche - If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.